# flutter doctor --android-licenses java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-doctor

I'm trying to install Flutter but when I run flutter doctor --android-licences I have this error
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

I have enable Android SDK Commande-line Tools on android studio.

I'm using a MacBook on MacOS BigSur 11.2.3 and the latest version of Android Studio

How to add this java module please ?

Comment: do you have the JavaJDK installed? along with Android SDK tools and command-line tools? Note: those are two different features (SDK tools and command-line tools)

Comment: How to know this ?

Comment: check your SDK manager in Android Studio
and do some googling

Answer (score 2):

1. First install android sdk-cli at android studio.
2. Go to android studio setting sdk-tool section then you find that: [for installing android-sdk-cli tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zlew.png)
3. after than hit this command `unset JAVA_OPTS`
   All worked fine for me

Comment: If possible attach screenshot for more clarification.

Comment: Hey @sidverma check the screenshot now